# Cómo buscar dinámicamente en c# y mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Esta es mi form

```
private void txt_buscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    Conexion_db sql = new Conexion_db();
    Camaras p = new Camaras();

    if (txt_buscar.Text != "")
    {
       string buscar = txt_buscar.Text;
       dg_camaras.DataSource = sql.buscar();
    }
    else
       p.Mostrar_camaras(dg_camaras);
}
```

y este es mi conexion donde se conecta el buscador

```
public DataTable buscar()
{
    open();

    string sql = @"select * from camaras where nombre like '%{0}%' or ip like '%{1}%'";
    MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion);
    DataSet Set = new DataSet();
    Adapter.Fill(Set, "tabla");
    conexion.Close();
    return Set.Tables["tabla"];
}
```

Comment: Y cual es tu problema exactamente?

Comment: mi problemas es que no funciona mi buscador no busca nada aparece en blanco y no se si esta mal lo que hice o hay otro ejemplo de buscador con mysql y c# y se brindaran un ejemplo me seria útil  por favor gracias

Comment: Usa Autoacomplete y para que la busqueda se dinamica.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

//este es el cambio que debes hacer en tu form

```
private void txt_buscar_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
  Conexion_db sql = new Conexion_db();

  Camaras p = new Camaras();

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_buscar.Text))
  {
        {
           string buscar = txt_buscar.Text;
            dg_camaras.DataSource = sql.buscar(buscar);
        }
        else
            p.Mostrar_camaras(dg_camaras);
   }

   //y esta es tu conexion donde se conecta el buscador

    public DataTable buscar(string busqueda)
    {
        open();

        string sql = string.Format(@"select * from camaras where nombre like '%{0}%' or ip like '%{1}%'", busqueda, string.Empty);

        MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion);
        DataSet Set = new DataSet();
        Adapter.Fill(Set, "tabla");
        conexion.Close();
        return Set.Tables["tabla"];

    }
```

Faltan datos sobre tu campo Ip por eso le puse en el string.Format como segundo parámetro un string vacío (string.Empty).

Espero que te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Suguiero que expliques cuál era el problema y cómo tu solución lo afronta. Un saludo.

Comment: Intenta no responder a alguien que no explica que le pasa la proxima vez.

Comment: Y por eso el negativo ? al menos esperen que cambie la respuesta. Arruinan la buena voluntad de los que respondemos. @jachguate

Comment: @jtaborga el voto negativo no es mio. Hice el comentario desde la cola de revisión con ánimo de mejorar la calidad de la misma, pero no voté tu respuesta. Como consejo, siendo yo mismo alguien que usualmente responde, es no ponerle mucha atención; no vas a evitar algún voto negativo de vez en cuando, incluso en respuestas que consideres excelentes. Es parte de la vida, pero si te esmeras en escribir respuestas de buena calidad, eso será esporádico.

Comment: Fijate que decis que hay que hacer un cambio y no decis cual es. Te sugiero vuelvas a revisar [answer] para ver como hacer una buena respuesta. Este codigo no se porque soluciona el problema que tenia quien pregunto (que dicho sea de paso, tampoco se cual es, pero si vos lo entendiste, explicalo tambien)